# How to load data from server using bootstrap-table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap-table plugin to display data from the server in an HTML table but I have not been able to get it to work. Here is the plugin URL: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

Here is my code:

```html
<table data-url="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"  data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]" data-search="true" data-toggle="table" id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I have loaded all necessary files but this will not work.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qoyho5jg/

Comment: Can you plz provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example ?

Comment: Hi, Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qoyho5jg/

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct JSON format:

```
{"total":4,"rows":[{"id":"1","name":"Item 1","price":"123"},{"id":"2","name":"Item 2","price":"123"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use method 'load'

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data);
```

you should notice that， data must be array and JS object

example:

```
data = "[{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}]"  # error
JSON.parse(data)  # parse json string to JS object
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  you put this code inside the head element of your web page

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.5.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->  
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.5.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales --> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.5.0/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>


 <html>
    <head>
       /* Put the scripts above here...*/

     /*You missed to place this script*/
     /*Of course you need to modify the correct URL and data 
      If you can give me your URL then I can post a sample ajax call for that*/


  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'data1.json',
    columns: [{
       field: 'id',
       title: 'Item ID'
       },
       {field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
       }, 
      {
         field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
       }, ]
      });

    </head>
    <body>

       <table data-url="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"  data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]" data-search="true" data-toggle="table" id="table">
       <thead>
       <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
          <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
          <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
          <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I checked your fiddle and there is no ajax/jquery call to pull the data.

Comment: @agentpx yes it's because JSFiddle disallows distant access to ajax requests if they aren't done in the art of rules. So user3072613 should have embed it directly within the integrated tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your json response is not well formated.
Pls take a look at your JSON data to match the required format as it's shown in the examples I found in the Github repository [demo.response.json](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/docs/data/data2/demo.response.json)

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Item 0",
        "price": "$0"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Item 2",
        "price": "$2"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: @user3072613 so maybe you can validate the answer ? :)